# Load image from mongoDb fail

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to view image in browser that i take from mongodb. the image correctly saved and I can download it perfectly using genghis.php but whenever I tried to load this using my own code whether ny using getBytes() or getResource(), the result only return bytes data such as this:

```
HDR¿£Ðß$iUßoÛT>‰oR¤? XG‡ŠÅ¯US[¹­ÆI“¥íJ¥éØ*$ä:7‰©Ûé¶ªO{7ü@ÙH§kk?ì<Ê»øÎí¾kktüqóÝ
```

Here is the code that I use to retrieve the image:

```
<?php

// Config  
$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbname = 'dbzuhra';
$colname = 'testData';  

// Connect to test database  
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");  
$db = $m->$dbname; 
$getGrid = $db->getGridFS();

$image = $getGrid->findOne(array('filename'=>'final_design.png'));

header('Content-type: image/png;');
$stream = $image->getResource();
while (!feof($stream)) {
    echo fread($stream, 8192);
}

?>
```

Is there any explanation to why this happen?

Comment: What if, instead of reading the stream resource you just did a getBytes on the file object? Just to test

Comment: @Sammaye: unfortunately, still has the same result

Comment: I think this has something more to do with either, a. the image being corrupt in which case most browsers would say so or b. something with the webserver not serving the images correctly

Comment: @Sammaye: yes, After I've tried using the same php file in another setup (Windows 7 with php 5.5.11/XAMPP and mongo driver PECL 1.45) it works just fine. previously, I use mac OSX 10.7 with MAMP (PHP 5.5.3 and PECL 1.4.5) and until now, it still gives an unexplainable result as above. So, I will open this thread and hopefully somebody will come with an answer :)

Comment: You will want to retag this question for that to get people who know your specific install. Maybe edit the question with the server details etc

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect header:

```
header('Content-type: image/png;');
                               ^--- don't put a semi-colon here
```

There is no image type `image/png;`. It's just `image/png`, and HTTP headers are delimited by line breaks, not semicolons.

Comment: thanks, but it still displays the same result. btw, I use this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongogridfsfile.getresource.php) as my resource and it seems to have the semicolon too..